# Talkback always reads application name when opening Jetpack Compose Dialog

Tags: accessibility, android-jetpack-compose, talkback

When opening a Dialog in Jetpack Compose, Talkback will always read the application label, before reading the Dialog title.

I have already tried setting the activity lable in the manifest to something different or just a space. While doing that, I noticed that talkback completely ignores the activity label and always goes for the outer application label.

Is there a way to stop Talkback from reading the application label entirely? And can I control what is read instead when opening a Dialog?